# SQL server strange math result?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I think Im going mad

```
SELECT 30.0/(-2.0)/5.0;
SELECT 30.0/-2.0/5.0;
```

[image]

what is happening here ?

### edit

who said that `x/(y)/z` will be `(x/y)/z` and not `x(y/z)` ? –

Comment: Unary minus has a lower precedence in SQL Server than multiply/divide. [Related connect item](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/731531/mathematical-operation-order)

Comment: @MartinSmith It looks like you're right (as usual), but that still blows my mind.  How does the unary minus cause it to be evaluated from right-to-left?  Also, [looks like SQL Server 2000 had a different precedence for this operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa276846(v=sql.80).aspx).

Comment: @MichaelFredrickson - BOL does say that but according to [this other item](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/127183/incorrect-evaluation-of-a-simple-arithmetic-expression-involving-a-fraction-with-a-negative-denominator) it's been like that since version 7.0. Not sure...

Comment: At least they are consistent: Unary + works the same way.  It's features like this that make me want a Disputability Level that will flag all the stuff Microsoft knows you can't trust, e.g. Scope_Identity() on a multiprocessor, but they haven't fixed or won't fix. [Ref] (http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/328811/scope-identity-sometimes-returns-incorrect-value#details)  Perhaps this is an opportunity for a 3rd party tool.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`SELECT 30.0/(-2.0)/5.0;` is fairly clear:

```
SELECT 30.0/(-2.0)=-15.0
-15.0/5.0=-3.0
```

the second select is being interpreted as: `SELECT 30.0/-(2.0/5.0);`

```
2.0/5.0=0.4
30.0/-0.4=-75.0
```

see: [Operator Precedence (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190276.aspx)

Comment: who said that x/(y)/z will be (x/y)/z and not x(y/z) ?

Comment: @Royi Namir, **See the link in my answer.** It shows that all `* (Multiply), / (Division), % (Modulo)` are handled before any `+ (Positive), - (Negative), + (Add), (+ Concatenate), - (Subtract), & (Bitwise AND), ^ (Bitwise Exclusive OR), | (Bitwise OR)`

Comment: @KM. The link in your answer contradicts the behavior here... "When two operators in an expression have the same operator precedence level, they are evaluated left to right based on their position in the expression."

Comment: @km the link doesnt help me much. Im repeating my question.

Comment: This is fairly clearly a bug in SQL Server, the minus sign should not invert the second division

Comment: @Andomar - It was originally an error (every other language has minus with higher precedence) but now it's documented behaviour and doesn't look likely that it will be changed as per comments [on the connect item I linked](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/731531/mathematical-operation-order)

Comment: it will follow the logic in the operator precedence as follows: it will look for a `~ (Bitwise NOT)` and not find one, it will look for `* (Multiply), / (Division), % (Modulo)`, and will find one: `30.0/( )`  it will resolve the `( )` by looking for a `~ (Bitwise NOT)` and not finding one.  it will then look for a `* (Multiply), / (Division), % (Modulo)`, which it finds and does `2.0/5.0`.  it then looks for the `+ (Positive), - (Negative) ...` and finds one and preforms it, it now has the `( )` as `-0.4` which it uses to complete the `30.0/( )` to get `-75.0`

Comment: @MartinSmith so its a bug ? it should produce the same result ?

Comment: @MartinSmith: The unary minus causes the division to invert, i.e. from x/y/z to z/y*z.  How can precendece explain that?

Comment: @KM: If that explanation were correct, it would fail without the minus sign too, but it doesn't.

Comment: Because division has higher precedence than minus. meaning that division binds first. i.e. `-2.0/5.0` is evaluated as `2.0/5.0` first then negated.

Comment: @MartinSmith: By that logic, both divisions in `30.0/-2.0/5.0` should "bind first"?

Comment: @Andomar, the first division binds as `30.0/( )` where `( )` is resolved as `-(2.0/5.0)`.

Comment: @KM: If it did, it would resolve `30.0/2.0/5.0;` as `30.0/(2.0/5.0)`, but it doesn't

Comment: **@Andomar no you wouldn't**. you get `30.0/(-(2.0/5.0))`. it resolves as `30/( )` the `( )` mean all remaining string. take that remaining string `-2.0/5.0` and you have the `/` preformed first (higher precedence) and then the `-` done last (lower precedence). that value `-0.4` is then used in the `( )` as: `30/(-0.4)` to get a finial value of `-75.0`. it is what it is, that is HOW TSQL is doing it. I think that negative `-` should be a higher precedence than it, then it would work more intuitively. **The question asks why the unexpected value, and this is how TSQL is getting that answer.**

Comment: @KM: Aha, so it interprets =2.0 as a minus operator followed by a number.  I'd thought "-2.0" was a atomic entity in logic.  All clear now!

Comment: @Andomar, you would think -2.0 was atomic.  if the `-` had a higher precedence, it could be atomic but it has a precedence lower than div, mult, modul.  When looking at `30.0/-2.0/5.0` it goes for the first `/` and breaks out `30.0` and `-2.0/5.0`.  then when considering `-2.0/5.0` it breaks it on the `/` again as `-(2.0/5.0)` for `-(0.4)`

Comment: @KM, get over it, look at Martin Smith's comment on OP. It is a bug, microsoft won't solve this ever and you've won 50 rep point for a wrong answer (well intended thoug) https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/731531/mathematical-operation-order

Comment: @daniloquio said `you've won 50 rep point for a wrong answer`. **ha, I properly explained why the calculation's value was not as expected.** I don't agree with the documented precedence of the `-` negative, but it is what it is.

Comment: @MartinSmith please supply the bug answer  as an answer.

Comment: @Royi Namir, you seem to want this to be a labeled a BUG to exonerate your code. While this is an inconvenient and crazy way to handle the precedence, sql server has had YEARS to change this and it is documented to work this way.  They have changed other items (utilizing SET commands to alter how it works and then deprecating the old behavior).  As you can see, there have been no changes in SQL Server 2012 for this, not set commands. You will have to write your code based on the TSQL language specifications (most likely dating back to Sybase) and move on.

Answer (score 3):

Your second select is executed as:

```
select 30.0/-(2.0/5.0)
```

Looks like the minus sign causes SQL Server to invert the last division-- pretty sure that's a bug!

Comment: who said that x/(y)/z will be (x/y)/z and not x(y/z) ? –

Comment: @RoyiNamir: Division is not associative-- it must always be x/(y)/x is the same as (x/y)/z, but not the same as x/(y/z)

Comment: sorry still dont understand. why  x/(y)/x is the same as (x/y)/z, but not the same as x/(y/z)  ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir: Division is executed from left to right.  So even without parenthesis, you'd do (x/y)/z.  But x/(y/z) has a very different meaning; it's equivalent to x/y*z.

Comment: **IT IS NOT A BUG!**, As I state in my answer and comments, start with `30.0/-2.0/5.0` and using the defined precedence you get `30.0/(-(2.0/5.0))`. it resolves as `30/( )` the `( )` means all the remaining string. take that remaining string `-2.0/5.0` and you have the `/` preformed first (higher precedence) and then the `-` done last (lower precedence). that value is `-0.4` and is then used in the `( )` as: `30/(-0.4)` to get a finial value of `-75.0`.  I personally feel that `-` negative should have a higher precedence, so this would work more intuitively, but this is how TSQL is doing it. .

Comment: @KM: It's definitely a bug-- they just can't fix it because of backward compatibility :P

Comment: it might not work how you think it should, but it is clearly defined to work this way, as crazy as that may be. so in my book, it is not a bug.  It is most likely, a poor decision by someone at Sybase.

Comment: @KM: Math is pretty clearly defined, what I think has nothing to do with it ;)

Comment: @KM, get over it, look at Martin Smith's comment on OP. It is a bug, microsoft won't solve this ever and you've won 50 rep point for a wrong answer (well intended thoug) https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/731531/mathematical-operation-order

Comment: @daniloquio said `you've won 50 rep point for a wrong answer`. **ha, I properly explained why the calculation's value was not as expected.** I don't agree with the documented precedence of the `-` negative, but it is what it is.

Comment: `It's definitely a bug-- they just can't fix it because of backward compatibility :P`  has there ever been a `set` option to make functionality optional, which leads to it being deprecated? yea, see this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176056.aspx  a bug is like [scope_identity() sometimes returning incorrect results](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/328811/scope-identity-sometimes-returns-incorrect-value)  calling this "crazy precedence specs" a bug is crazy, write your code based on the language specifications (most likely dating back to Sybase) and move on.